# Database Rows into Single Column (From a few tables over)?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2019

Working through a very disjointed database (had to find the keys to each table myself), need to get a workable dataset out of it that require bridging about 4 tables for the main dataset. My issues is on Table 2 each Person account get attached to multiple accounts then then lead to status codes. So instead of the desired:

| Person | ETC | Codes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | XXX | Code1, Code2, Etc |
| P2 | XXX | Code1, Code2, Etc |

It instead outputs:

| Person | ETC | Codes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | XXX | Code1 |
| P1 | XXX | Code2 |
| P2 | XXX | Code1 |
| P2 | XXX | Code2 |

the code is currently close to this:

```
SELECT P.PersonID, (A few more P.values), CD.Codes
FROM (((Table1 as P 
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 ON P.PersonID = t2.PersonFID) 
INNER JOIN Table3 as T3 ON T2.ID2 = T3.ID)
INNER JOIN TableCD as CD ON T3.ID2 = CD.ID)
```

I spent hours trying to instead maybe query and link them through nested selects using WHERE PersonID IN(etc) but that ended roughly the same. I am not able to GROUP BY to set them all the same either. I am not sure what to do and any help would be very appreciated. And I apologize if there is already an answer I have been pulling my hair out and have looked over a lot but I could have missed it. The end goal is to create a new table with all the information.

Comment: Please show the sample data. Looks like you need [string_agg()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I apologize for taking so long, busy weekend. Which part of the data sample fo you mean? As in the codes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL 2016 or later, there is a very quick solution, so DB has a `string_split` function which returns table data. The query that returns the result you need:

```
select t1.PERSON, t1.ETC, t2.Value as CODES from table1 t1 
cross apply string_split(t1.CODES, ',') t2;
```

If you are a prior version of SQL 2016 then you can manually create your own function, for example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].StringSplit
(
    @String  VARCHAR(MAX), @Separator CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @RESULT TABLE(Value VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN     
 DECLARE @SeparatorPosition INT = CHARINDEX(@Separator, @String ),
        @Value VARCHAR(MAX), @StartPosition INT = 1
 
 IF @SeparatorPosition = 0  
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @RESULT VALUES(@String)
   RETURN
  END
     
 SET @String = @String + @Separator
 WHILE @SeparatorPosition > 0
  BEGIN
   SET @Value = SUBSTRING(@String , @StartPosition, @SeparatorPosition- @StartPosition)
 
   IF( @Value <> ''  ) 
    INSERT INTO @RESULT VALUES(@Value)
   
   SET @StartPosition = @SeparatorPosition + 1
   SET @SeparatorPosition = CHARINDEX(@Separator, @String , @StartPosition)
  END    
     
 RETURN
END
```

After then you can use it on your query:

```
select t1.PERSON, t1.ETC, t2.Value as CODES from table1 t1 
cross apply dbo.StringSplit(t1.CODES, ',') t2
```

Comment: I made an attempt at trying this one. (Had to stop as MS access was not playing along with this nicely so spent a day organizing it manually, would like to avoid that in future). I feel like I am missing something, sorry I am still learning a lot about sql. I see access has a version of the split() but I am not sure if it functions this way